# Minha lógica de verificação de char está errada?

Tags: java

Estou lendo uma linha de um arquivo e preciso que o loop pare quando encontrar um espaço ou um =. Eu fiz o código abaixo porém não está funcionando, mesmo tendo espaço ou = na linha, ele continua o loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){
    if (line.charAt(i) != ' ' || line.charAt(i) != '='){
    instruction += line.charAt(i);
    continue;
}
```

Não consigo encontrar meu erro.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o break ao invés do continue

```
 for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
  if (line.charAt(i) == ' ' || line.charAt(i) == '=') {
   break;
 }
  instruction += line.charAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Para PARAR o loop, utiliza-se o comando `break`. O `continue` na verdade pula para o próximo item do loop.
2. Existe um erro de lógica no código abaixo:

   ```
   if (line.charAt(i) != ' ' || line.charAt(i) != '=')
   ```

Repare que o `if` está verificando se o `char` é diferente de `' '` OU diferente de `'='`.
Como não existe a possibilidade de o `char` ser igual a ambos, a condição SEMPRE será `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Gustavo, você pode usar o break; e ajustar alguns detalhes do seu código, como fechar o "}" do laço for também.
Segue exemplo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){
    if (line.charAt(i) != ' ' && line.charAt(i) != '='){
       instruction += line.charAt(i);
   } else {
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Essa lógica resolve, dessa forma a String instruction não vai ter  espaço em branco e o símbolo de igualdade.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){
        if (line.charAt(i) == ' ' || line.charAt(i) == '='){
            continue;
        }
        instruction += line.charAt(i);
    }
```